# Exclude weeks starting with Saturday from output

Tags: php

I have this script which displays the start date an end date for each week in a month.

I would like to somehow filter out the first week that may start with Saturday.. For example if we take August 2015 as an example, the first week

```
<?php       
$textdt="01 Aug 2015";
$dt= strtotime( $textdt);
$currdt=$dt;
$nextmonth=strtotime($textdt."+1 month");
$i=0;
do 
{
    $weekday= date("w",$currdt);
    $nextday=7-$weekday;
    $endday=abs($weekday-7);
    $startarr[$i]=$currdt;
    $endarr[$i]=strtotime(date("Y-m-d",$currdt)."+$endday day");
    $currdt=strtotime(date("Y-m-d",$endarr[$i])."+1 day");
    echo "Week ".($i+1)." - ". date("d-m-Y",$startarr[$i])." to ". date("d-m-Y",$endarr[$i])."<br>";
     $i++;

}while($endarr[$i-1]<$nextmonth);
?>
```

**Current output**

```
Week 1 - 01-08-2015 to 02-08-2015
Week 2 - 03-08-2015 to 09-08-2015
Week 3 - 10-08-2015 to 16-08-2015
Week 4 - 17-08-2015 to 23-08-2015
Week 5 - 24-08-2015 to 30-08-2015
Week 6 - 31-08-2015 to 06-09-2015
```

**Desired output**

```
Week 1 - 03-08-2015 to 09-08-2015
Week 2 - 10-08-2015 to 16-08-2015
Week 3 - 17-08-2015 to 23-08-2015
Week 4 - 24-08-2015 to 30-08-2015
Week 5 - 31-08-2015 to 06-09-2015
```

Comment: when you get the week you can check the first day of the week, if it is sat you skip it.

Comment: You want all to start with monday?

Comment: no i just want to exclude the first week if it begins with a saturday.. some months like Dec-15 the week starts with Tuesday, those are fine to keep.

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain, any sample you can share that can be worked into the code i shared?

Comment: Check the manual for `date` to find out how to get the week day … and then put that into a simple if condition.

Comment: put `if($weekday != 6)` before `echo` statement

Comment: @chetanameta thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check `date("D",$startarr[$i]) !== "Sat"` or you can use `if($weekday != 6)`

```
if(date("D",$startarr[$i]) !== "Sat") {
    echo "Week ".($i+1)." - ". date("d-m-Y",$startarr[$i])." to ". date("d-m-Y",$endarr[$i])."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an if

```
<?php       
$textdt="01 Aug 2015";
$dt= strtotime( $textdt);
$currdt=$dt;
$nextmonth=strtotime($textdt."+1 month");
$i=0;
$weekIndex = 1;
do 
{
    $weekday= date("w",$currdt);
    if($weekday != 6) {
        $nextday=7-$weekday;
        $endday=abs($weekday-7);
        $startarr[$i]=$currdt;
        $endarr[$i]=strtotime(date("Y-m-d",$currdt)."+$endday day");
        $currdt=strtotime(date("Y-m-d",$endarr[$i])."+1 day");
        echo "Week ".($weekIndex++)." - ". date("d-m-Y",$startarr[$i])." to ". date("d-m-Y",$endarr[$i])."<br>";
    }
     $i++;

}while($endarr[$i-1]<$nextmonth);
?>
```

Edit: added `$weekIndex`